# Check if there are more than 1 argument

Tags: c, if-statement, arguments, command-line-arguments

I have a simple program that encrypts message using `Caesar Cipher`.

The program works well, but I am unable to check whether the user is entering more than 1 argument. If he is, I need to break and prompt the user to enter the correct number of arguments which is `1`.

If you enter more than 1 argument in terminal, say `./caesar 13 56 hello` it will still work but it shouldn't

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int indexKey = 0;

    string message; 

    if (argc < 2 || atoi(argv[0]) < 0 || atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {   
        printf("Please enter a non-negative integer as an argument.\n"); 
        return 1; 
    } else {   
        indexKey = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
```

How do I prevent the user from entering too many arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be checking if `argc != 2` instead of `argc < 2`.

Also, don't bother checking `argv[0]`, since that represents the name of the executable that was run.

Comment: Thank you. Mind my stupid question, but when we say `argc != 2` what are we actually saying in terms of pseudo-code?

Comment: That says "if the number of arguments is not 2", keeping in mind that the executable counts as the first argument.